# Detecting when Laravel Dusk is running

Tags: php, laravel, testing, integration-testing, laravel-dusk

Often in Laravel I need to detect the environment to avoid triggering certain code while running tests, like logging or sending an email:

```
if (!app()->environment("testing")) {
    Mail::to($email)->queue(new WelcomeEmail($transaction->id));
}
```

This works fine when the environment is set to `testing` in 3 of my 4 environment files (local and CI/CD unit tests, Dusk on CI/CD), but my `.env.dusk.local` file - which [I need](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#environment-handling) to run Laravel Dusk locally - has a `local` environment, and in these cases Dusk triggers the sending of emails, logs, etc.

The cleanest solution I can see for this would be to detect whether Dusk is running in any environment - I'm aware there's an `app()->runningUnitTests()` method, but don't know of an equivalent for Dusk.

Comment: Dusk can be told to use a separate `.env` file; https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/dusk#environment-handling - perhaps you could set `APP_ENV=dusk` there?

Comment: @ceejayoz Please read the body of the question, I'm already using that file and already linked to that documentation. The problem with setting a custom value is that Dusk requires it to be suffixed to the filename, and I'm not sure if it will correctly pull the environment from an `.env.dusk.dusk` file or recognise any environments other than `local`, `production` and `testing`.

Comment: I'm saying for local, create `.env.dusk.local` and set `APP_ENV=dusk` in that file, so that running Dusk locally should let you do `app()->environment('dusk')` checks.

Comment: @ceejayoz That link of the documentation specifically says the suffix needs to match the environment value, so if I set the environment value to `dusk` the .env file will need to be named `.env.dusk.dusk`.

Comment: The suffix needs to match the **non-Dusk** environment that's initiating Dusk, i.e. what's in your main `.env`. Once in it, you should be able to *override* the APP_ENV value; i.e. "when Dusk is running in `local` environment, set the environment to `dusk`".

Comment: Dusk essentially is an automated browser testing library. I think your best bet is to find out what user agent the Dusk browser sends (or if you can customise that) and check that since Dusk will be hitting your actual working website. However: (1) Should you really be doing this? Browser testing is meant to simulate a real user as much as possible, if you don't want that then maybe using Dusk for those routes is not appropriate (2) should the environment that dusk is targeting really be sending emails? If it's a testing environment then it should at least use mailtrap

Comment: @ceejayoz I see what you're saying now, and I've just tested - this does work. Thanks for your help and feel free to add an answer.

Comment: Done. Do pay attention to @apokryfos's note about the specific example of mail, though; you might be better off with `MAIL_DRIVER=log`.

Comment: @apokryfos 1. Simulate a real user as much as possible within reason, but I don't really want to simulate the sending of emails that don't need to be sent. I need to test that my payments are working, but don't need to receive the emails that come with them - I have separate unit tests for those which use `Mail:fake`. 2. If you mean setting up a separate mail service for testing, that would probably be the most complete solution, but it's also overkill and premature optimisation for me at the moment, when what I have works fine at my scale.

Comment: @HashimAziz (and for logging, you can do `LOG_DRIVER=null` to stop logging entirely, or `LOG_DRIVER=single/daily` to log to the `storage/logs` directory text files.)

Comment: @ceejayoz Interesting, I was aware of `log` for mail but not of `null` for the logs - if I go through my code and find I'm only detecting Dusk when mailing and logging I might just opt for that solution instead.

Comment: I mentioned https://mailtrap.io/ which is intended to be used for testing. When you use that then all emails are "trapped" in your account's mailbox regardless of who the recipient is.  I personally use this for testing environments and it works nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dusk will check for a file `.env.dusk.<environment>`.

Using `local` environment as an example, it will check `.env.dusk.local`. Setting `APP_ENV=dusk` in that file will permit you to add checks like `if(app()->environment('dusk'))` where necessary.

As noted in the comments, though, for the specific example of sending mail or logging, you're generally better off overriding `MAIL_DRIVER` or `LOG_CHANNEL` to something suitable for testing, like `MAIL_DRIVER=log` or `LOG_CHANNEL=daily`, so you can still test that functionality without sending actual emails.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to *ceejayoz*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77361743/1191147) and to explicitly spell out what I did to solve this, I changed the environment variables in both my `env.dusk.local` (for running Dusk locally) and `.env.dusk.testing` (for running Dusk in CI/CD) to:

```
APP_ENV=dusk
```

This overrides the environment variable in `.env` and allows me to do:

```
if (!app()->environment("testing", "dusk")) { // if not running unit/feature or Dusk tests
    Mail::to($email)->queue(new WelcomeEmail($transaction->id));
}
```

Comment: super mega personal recommendation, you should not have this type of code in your production code. Of course nothing is perfect, so you may end up with this, but for your specific case, you would just need to change the mail driver/connection and no mail is sent (or sent to the right service), so you do not need to distinguish anything. It will also help with testing, as if you do `!app()->environment("testing"`, you are not going to test, ever, that the right mail is being sent, so you are missing something there (test). This is my grain of sand to contribute to this.

Comment: @matiaslauriti You're right about this condition not allowing the mail unit tests to run, I realised this after and have since changed it to only detect for Dusk. As a general case I've realised setting `null` (or worse, `log` for mails) in `.env` files is not the answer, they're useful for things like logging which should always have the same behaviour across a single environment, but you can only get more granular control from doing it in the code - for example, making one email send in Dusk tests while skipping over another, in the same environment. I feel a good codebase should use both.